# How to initialize GoogleCredentials object without using credentials files created by gcloud auth login

Tags: python, google-compute-engine

To connect to GCE i can use the credentials files created by *gcloud auth login*. Like this:

```
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
compute = build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

def list_instances(compute, project, zone):
    result = compute.instances().list(project=project, zone=zone).execute()
    return result['items']

instances = list_instances(compute, 'project', 'zone')
```

Above code uses the credentials stored at ~/.config/gcloud

I would like to initialize GoogleCredentials object by directly setting values inside the code. Like client_id, client_secret..

PS: Above code is from this link : https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/python-guide#gettingstarted

Comment: is it ok if u initialize google credentials using the client_id, secret, refresh token from ~/.config/gcloud ??

Comment: I guess.. do you have a code for that? i would like to try it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is another way to initialize GoogleCredentials object:

```
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import AccessTokenCredentials
from urllib import urlencode
from urllib2 import Request , urlopen, HTTPError
import json

def access_token_from_refresh_token(client_id, client_secret, refresh_token):
    request = Request('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
        data=urlencode({
            'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
            'client_id': client_id,
            'client_secret': client_secret,
            'refresh_token': refresh_token
        }),
        headers={
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    )
    response = json.load(urlopen(request))
    return response['access_token']

access_token = access_token_from_refresh_token('client_id', 'client_secret', 'refresh_token')

credentials = AccessTokenCredentials(access_token, "MyAgent/1.0", None)

compute = build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

def list_instances(compute, project, zone):
    result = compute.instances().list(project=project, zone=zone).execute()
    return result['items']

instances = list_instances(compute, 'project', 'zone')
```

--
values for client_id, secret, refresh_token taken from ~/.config/gcloud/credentials

Comment: works for now.. i would have preferred to not add the refresh token, as i dont know when that will expire. Can you tell me how the Refresh token  works so i can update the value as and when needed.

Answer (score 0):

The right way is to use P12 or JSON Credentials for service accounts  shown [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/service-accounts)